# Sitefinity Staging & Synchronization - destination doesn't contain a site with name 'SFDev'

Tags: sitefinity

I am trying to use sitefinity *Staging & Synchronization* feature.

I did exactly what is told in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-mbXODZ0MI

But receiving following error.
**You cannot sync the data, because the destination doesn't contain a site with name 'SFDev'.**
[image]

I am moving data from SFDev to SFStaging. So how could the destination name be **SFDev**.

SFDev - Running on Casini Web server
SFStaging - running on local IIS

Not able to find any information on this error. Any suggestions here please?

Product Version: **7.1.5200.0**

Answer (score 1):

The site names have to be the same. When you make the first move it is all "manual". The code and DBs must match from the beginning. The sync tool is NOT a database mover it only sync specific areas of it. Please reference these instructions.

http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/syncing-of-data

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the source or destination site can be running Casini Web server while executing a SiteSync.

Have a look here:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/prerequisites-and-restrictions

> All sites must be deployed on IIS.